# node.js for loop with class

Tags: node.js, loops

Recently I found a strange problem and don't know why it happen. Here is the code:

```
return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
        try{
            var target=[1,2,3,4,5];
            var notify={id:'',text:'aaa'};
            var nn=[];
            for(var t in target){
                temp=notify; //not work
                //temp={}; //work...
                console.log(t+':'+target[t]);
                temp['id']=target[t];
                nn.push(temp);
            }
            console.log(nn);
            resolve();
        }catch(err){
            reject(err);
        }
    });
```

If I run with that "not work" code, it will print out:

```
[{id:'5',text:'aaa'},{id:'5',text:'aaa'},...]
```

Clearly, this is not what I expected. If I comment that "not work" code, and run with temp={}, it will print out:

```
[{id:'1',text:'aaa'},{id:'2',text:'aaa'},...]
```

That is correct... at least it is in my expected. I want to know why it happen, and how to solve it if I really need to load the notify in temp first, then change its id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp=notify` does not do a deep copy of the object, it only copies the reference to the object, so when you do several times

```
temp=notify;
nn.push(temp);
```

you'll actually push several times `notify`. Here's how you can wrap your head around this concept better:

```js
const src = { some: 'value' }
const copy = src;
copy.some = 'other value';
console.log(src, copy);
```

When you do `temp={}` however, you create a new object, so you'll push a new object every time, and that is why "it works".

Comment: Agree with this answer. I was wonder if every "var a=b;" is just a reference of the object? Or it just happen in for loop.... Per now I am try to test the function "var a=b(index);" run in for loop to find out what will happen.